# while command not working when bash script is sourced in tcsh?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, tcsh, csh

I had made a `bash` shell script which include `while` command but when I run the script using `source` command on terminal, it gives a syntax error message.

I need to use `source` because I have to set the environment variable on the terminal, which can't be used without `source`.

`echo $shell` gives : `/bin/csh`
shell is not interactive
output of `ps -p $$` gives `CMD : tcsh`

script is:

```
#! /bin/bash
i=1
while read line
do 
echo "$line $i"
echo
i=$((i+1))

done < seed.txt
```

error is:

```
i=1: Command not found.
while: Expression Syntax.
```

Comment: Without seeing the script, the error message, and the expected behaviour, it's very hard to say _anything_ useful. Is your interactive shell also `bash`?

Comment: updated the question sir.

Comment: Is your interactive shell bash? What operating system is this? What is the output of `ps -p $$`? What is the output of `echo $SHELL`? Please [edit] your question and add these details.

Comment: ... sounds like you are sourcing it into a csh

Comment: updated the question

Comment: You can't source a bash script into a tcsh interpreter any more than you can `#include` Java source into a C compiler. They're two different, mutually incompatible languages.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/env2/ might help

Answer (score 15):

This error?

```
$ tcsh
tcsh> source while.sh 
i=1: Command not found.
while: Expression Syntax.
tcsh> exit
```

Csh/tcsh is a different shell than POSIX sh or Bash. Trying to run a script in sh syntax in (t)csh is not going to work.

> I need to use `source` because I have to set the environment variable on the terminal, which can't be used without `source`.

Make it an actual exported environment variable with `setenv`:

```
tcsh> cat hello.sh 
echo "hello, $name"
tcsh> bash hello.sh
hello, 
tcsh> setenv name vikas
tcsh> bash hello.sh
hello, vikas
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to run a *bash* shell script, and based on that change *tcsh* variables (if this is really what you need):

Write the shell script *myscript.bash* like this:

```
ANSWER="$((6*7))  'quoted'"
echo "setenv answer '${ANSWER//\'/\'\\\'\'}'"
```

Then run it from tcsh:

```
bash myscript.bash >myscript.tcsh.out
source myscript.tcsh.out
echo "$answer"
```

This will print:

```
42  'quoted'
```

The substitution in `${ANSWER//\'/\'\\\'\'}` makes it work if the value contains single quotes (`'`). The uses of double quotes (`"`) make it work if the value contains whitespace.

It's possible to send multiple variables to *tcsh*, by adding mor `echo "setenv ..."` lines.

However, there are simpler solutions (see in other answers) if it's OK to start a new (sub)shell instead of changing variables in an existing shell process.